# Calculate the remaining days on view Laravel, negative days if date has passed

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

These are the values on my database, I just need to get the remaining days of each today:

[image: SQL table]

```html
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInDays($patient->date_end) }}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? There doesnt seem to be anything wrong with your code assuming that you have declared date_end in the dates array in your patient model.

Comment: @user3532758 no error , its just that i have a row where in may 7 2022 has 1 days remaining but today was may 8 2022, it gave me like the difference , i need something like negative value if its exceed to the date now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the problem solved but , im confused with the may 7 , which is the 3rd
> row should give me a negative value

If you want to get the negative values, you would need to pass `false` as the second parameter of the `diffInDays` function.

```
Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInDays($patient->date_end, false)
```

The second parameter sets whether you want the absolute difference or not. Default is true, which returns absolute difference.

Comment: thank you so much, now i got the negative value exactly what i needed. i also removed my answer , sorry im not so good with stack overflow

Comment: glad i was able to help. nothing to be sorry about, we have all been new and lost at some point. good luck!

Answer (score 2):

To get the difference between two date you could make use of carbon in following ways:

```
$start = Carbon::parse('2022-04-30');
$end = Carbon::parse('2022-05-06');
$diff = $start->diffInDays($end);
```

Above, code should give you the difference between this `$start` and `$end` date difference in days. Here, instead of static date `2022-04-30`. You might have to pass it using object or array values. Something like `$start = Carbon::parse($patient->date_start);`

But, in case you are saying to find the difference between current date and `date_end` then you could do:

```
$end = Carbon::parse($patient->date_end);
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInDays($end) }}
```

This will give you the difference between and end date.

And, looking at the small details you have provided, it looks like you are not parsing the data. You might have to parse it first so that it could find the diff.

If you want to get negative values, you might have to pass `false` as the second parameter,`diffInDays($patient->date_end, false)`. Other than this, sometimes still you might get incorrect values, and this could be because of `timezone`. Let's say you are in `GMT -7`, and on UTC its already a new date but in your timezone its still a previous day. On this case, you might see 0 day remaining, even if it is 2 days remaining according to your timezone.

On that case, you might have to pass timezone as well.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInDays($end,false)->timezone('America/New_York'));
```

Comment: it worked but some of the rows gave wrong values , for example the may 7 2022 has 1 days remaining , and today was may 8 2022 which is im confused

Comment: @MaeMae Add extra conditions to check if date_end is less than current date.

Comment: @MaeMae this could be because of timezone as well. you can take a look at my answer, I have updated it.

Comment: this is great , with timezone . im currently using this with same timezone , but this good for global use

Comment: @MaeMae by default, it uses `Europe/London`, actually, its better to get that timezone value dynamically, probably from users table or from wherever you store. Else, all time might be converted to that timezone even if another user is from another timezone.